# Android: Log W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: android

every time i swap activity i get these errors in my log. The application works fine but i just recieves both these errors when i swap to any activity and it has never done this before.[image]

Really could use some help in stopping this.